# Workbooks Open Method Works Every Other Time

Tags: excel, vba, macos, file

I am using the `Workbooks.Open` Method in Excel VBA on a Mac to copy data from rows in one sheet into rows in another.  My code was written several years ago and worked every time until `Office 365`.  The macro is very long so I won't post it all here.  The code that I seem to be having problems with follows:

```
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename 
Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
```

The code works every other time I run the macro.  The first time I run it the file doesn't open.  The next time it does.  Every other time I run it, it works.

I set a watch for `FileToOpen` and I get the same result every time in debug.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the procedure without a value in FileToOpen,
the second time , the fileToOpen have the value

```
'1st  FileToOpen = ""
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
```

' the 2st time the file to open have a value , thats why it works!
The solution :

```
dim FileToOpenPath as string 

FileToOpenPath = Application.GetOpenFilename()

FileToOpen =  Workbooks.Open(FileToOpenPath)
```